# Clone elements in DOM with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress-theming

I need to clone an element from the DOM to make it fly to a basket. I'm using `.clone()` from jQuery. The problem is when I first click the element, it clones twice instead of once, and when I click it again it clones once. Why does this happen?

My piece of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.addd-body').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().clone().prependTo('.carro');
});});
```

You can see the working code on [Mashini website](http://hoteles.mashini.cl/sabana-mashini-hotel-200-hilos-6/).

Answer (score 1):

Please update when you figure out the cause; I think there is more to it since your code looks fine.

Test1: try changing your code to stop propagation

```
$('.addd-body').click(function(e) {
    $(this).parent().clone().prependTo('.carro');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Test2: try scoping your click events down to the actual link

```
$('.addd-body').delegate('click', 'a.item_add', function() {
    $(this).closest('ul').clone().prependTo('.carro');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change $('.addd-body').click(...) to $('.addd-body > a').click(...)
It seems that you have a handler attached to the LI element that then propagates to the anchoe elements and runs once more.

Comment: thnkz, that works, i added that and a .parent() to get the entire row

`$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.addd-body > a').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().clone().prependTo('.carro');
 });
});`

Comment: Yeah, forgot about the parent() stuff, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.item_add').click(function() {
    $(this).parents(".body-cart:first").clone().prependTo('.carro');
});});
```